# Strange binary number representation

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, softwareserial

I have a very simple sketch, something like this:

```
int aFour = 4; 
softwareSerial.print(4,BIN); 
softwareSerial.print(aFour,BIN);
```

Which gives the following output:

```
1001
0011
```

Why don't they print both as `0100`?

EDIT: the output was in one line : `10010011`, I falsely asumed the output should be split into twice 4 bits.

Comment: Works for me. How it's even separated? Maybe it's `100` `100` `11` or so because you did just `print` not `println` ...

Comment: I also got a `100` when I tried it. @KIIV did raised a good point about `println`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `print` never prints leading zeroes (how many *should* it print anyway?).
- `print` doesn't start a new line - you need `println` for that

So you get your `4` in binary printed twice followed by something else (not sure what - maybe something else in your program that you're not showing us?): `10010011`

That's `100 100 11` when split up.

Comment: I indeed falsely assumed the output to be split 4 bits each. `println` clarified the issue. The lagging `11` originated from some other print statement not displayed in my question above. Thanks!